# Word for "of or characteristic of a clan or clans"?

Tags: single-word-requests

*Tribal* is to *tribe* as ??? is to *clan*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try [Clannish](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/clannish)

**clannish** [ klan-ish ]

adjective

1. of, relating to, or characteristic of a clan.

Comment: Can't be bettered.